# On page load, check a condition and show modal pop up in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, modal-dialog

I am very new to AngularJS. I am trying to show a modal pop up in angular JS. 
I have tried modal on button click from the dialog demo tutorial of angular.

What I need now is , on page load, there should be a condition checked, based on which pop up should be shown. I have a idea like to click this button on page load automatically. But I don't think that is a good approach. I have researched for various options, but could not find the relevant solution.

Any help can be appreciated.

Following is what has done so far from [this](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/dialog) demo.

HTML :

```
<div ng-controller="TestCtrl" layout="row" ng-cloak style="height: 300px">
  <style>
  .edgePadding {
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
  }

 </style>
<div layout="column" layout-align="center start" layout-padding flex>
<div class="inset"> test test test </div>

<div class="dialog-demo-content" layout="column" layout-align="center center" style="width:100%">
  <md-button class="md-primary md-raised edgePadding" ng-click="openFromLeft()" >
    test
  </md-button>
</div>
```

app.js

```
angular.module('mytestapp')

.controller('TestCtrl', function($scope, $mdDialog) {
   $scope.openFromLeft = function() {
    $mdDialog.show(
      $mdDialog.alert()
        .clickOutsideToClose(true)
        .title('Opening from the left')
        .textContent('Closing to the right!')
        .ariaLabel('Left to right demo')
        .ok('Nice!')
        // You can specify either sting with query selector
        .openFrom('#left')
        // or an element
        .closeTo(angular.element(document.querySelector('#right')))
    );
  };

  $scope.openOffscreen = function() {
    $mdDialog.show(
      $mdDialog.alert()
        .clickOutsideToClose(true)
        .title('Opening from offscreen')
        .textContent('Closing to offscreen')
        .ariaLabel('Offscreen Demo')
        .ok('Amazing!')
        // Or you can specify the rect to do the transition from
        .openFrom({
          top: -50,
          width: 30,
          height: 80
        })
        .closeTo({
          left: 1500
        })
    );
  };
})
```

Any basic approach is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

provide an ng-init on the parent div

```
<div ng-controller="TestCtrl" ng-init="loadFun()" layout="row" ng-cloak style="height: 300px">
```

Now in your controller

```
$scope.loadFun=function(){
 $mdDialog.show(
  $mdDialog.alert()
    .clickOutsideToClose(true)
    .title('Opening from offscreen')
    .textContent('Closing to offscreen')
    .ariaLabel('Offscreen Demo')
    .ok('Amazing!')
    // Or you can specify the rect to do the transition from
    .openFrom({
      top: -50,
      width: 30,
      height: 80
    })
    .closeTo({
      left: 1500
    })
);
 }
```